# Mouseleave overwrites the click when using same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a rating system in javascript.

I want to execute same function on click and mouseenter but opposite function on mouseleave because of which mouseleave overwrites the clicks function.

See what i am trying to say. This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rate_btn").on({
    click: function(eve) {
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass("rate_btn_active");
      var current_rating = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#current_given_rating").html(current_rating);
      $("#check_click").html("See its working: " + current_rating);
      $("#msg").html("But because of mouseleave its not retaining.");
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass("rate_btn_active");
      var current_rating = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#current_given_rating").html(current_rating);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass("rate_btn_active");
      $("#current_given_rating").html("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rate_btn {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 5px 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
.rate_btn_active {
  background-color: #11AB0E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check_click"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
<div>
  <div id="1" class="rate_btn"></div>
  <div id="2" class="rate_btn"></div>
  <div id="3" class="rate_btn"></div>
  <div id="4" class="rate_btn"></div>
  <div id="5" class="rate_btn"></div>
  <div id="current_given_rating" style="margin: 10px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: once clicked, on second time hover i wanted it to look just like the first time it is. No opacity.

Comment: Do you mean that if 5 are selected, but you then hover over the 3rd, then 4 and 5 will not look selected while you are hovering?  I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes and thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I just edited it again, adding inner divs and changing css to make it function super smooth without flickering when your mouse goes in the spaces between boxes.  I hope it's good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's similar to your code.  We're going to use the "active" class to dynamically show all boxes up to and including the current one the mouse is on.  But when we actually click, we'll add a permanent "selected" class that will persist even after mouseleave erases the "active" class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rate_btn").on({
    click: function(eve) {
      $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('selected');
      var current_rating = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#current_given_rating").html(current_rating);
    },
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass("rate_btn_active");
      var current_rating = $(this).attr('id');
      $("#current_given_rating").html(current_rating);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass("rate_btn_active");
      $("#current_given_rating").html("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rate_btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  float:left;
}
.rate_btn div{
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

#ratingbox:hover .selected div{background-color: #D8D8D8;}

#ratingbox:hover .r1.rate_btn_active div{background-color: rgb(220,30,30)!important;}
#ratingbox:hover .r2.rate_btn_active div{background-color: rgb(200,50,30)!important;}
#ratingbox:hover .r3.rate_btn_active div{background-color: rgb(200,200,30)!important;}
#ratingbox:hover .r4.rate_btn_active div{background-color: rgb(50 ,200,30)!important;}
#ratingbox:hover .r5.rate_btn_active div{background-color: rgb(30 ,220,30)!important;}

.r1.selected div, .r1.rate_btn_active div { background-color: rgb(220,30,30);}
.r2.selected div, .r2.rate_btn_active div { background-color: rgb(200,50,30);}
.r3.selected div, .r3.rate_btn_active div { background-color: rgb(200,200,30);}
.r4.selected div, .r4.rate_btn_active div { background-color: rgb(50 ,200,30);}
.r5.selected div, .r5.rate_btn_active div { background-color: rgb(30 ,220,30);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="check_click"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="ratingbox">
  <div id="1" class="rate_btn r1"><div></div></div>
  <div id="2" class="rate_btn r2"><div></div></div>
  <div id="3" class="rate_btn r3"><div></div></div>
  <div id="4" class="rate_btn r4"><div></div></div>
  <div id="5" class="rate_btn r5"><div></div></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id="current_given_rating" style="margin: 10px"></div>
```

Comment: can you please tell whats the better way?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing how can we add different colour to boxes? Like, 1st is red, 2nd is shade of red, 3rd is yellow, 4th is shade of yellow and fifth is green.

Comment: @RaghavGarg Ok, I edited to have colors like you say. It's just css changes. (and adding a class to the items in html).  If you're working with friends, maybe ask them to upvote this question a few more times :)